# mysql generating report (columns into rows and then comparision)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mysql table that looks like this

```
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|date     | quarter |   value1| value2|     value3| company  |
-------------------------------------------------------------|
3/30/2016 | q1 2016 |       1|      2|          3|  A        |
-------------------------------------------------------------|
6/30/2016 | q2 2016 |     1.1|    2.1|        3.1|  A        |
-------------------------------------------------------------|
9/30/2016 | q3 2016 |     1.2|    2.2|        3.2|  A        |
-------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I would like to create report like this that allows comparison of values for different time periods.

```
|------------------------------------------|
|Values  | q1 2016 |    q2 2016 | q3 2016  | 
------------------ ------------------------|
value1   |       1 |         1.1|      1.2 |
-------------------------------------------|
value2   |       2 |         2.1|      2.2 |
-------------------------------------------|
value3   |       3 |         3.1|       3.2|
-------------------------------------------|
```

I am new to mysql. Any directions how to get this results will be very appreciated.

Edit : I looked into pivot and unpivot. Though mysql doesnt offer this function, there are workaround. But I still cant figure out how I will get value1, value2, value3 (ie column header) in rows in results.

Comment: search for `unpivoting`

Comment: I looked into pivot and unpivot. Though mysql doesnt offer this function, there are workaround. But I still cant figure out how I will get value1, value2, value3 (ie column header) in rows in results.